# window.open() is not opening the correct window size on second click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open an image in a new window but when I click on the link multiple times, the new window's size is not consistent with what I resize it to. Why is it that the second time I click on the anchor tag, the window does not open into the size I specified? (The first time I click the anchor tag, it opens as I expect with the right size)

JS

```
<script>
    function openW(a) {
        var i = new Image();
        i.src = "somepic.png";

        // open up a new blank
        var w = window.open("", "", "scrollbars=yes");

        w.resizeTo(i.width, i.height/2);
        w.document.write('<img src="' + i.src + '">');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a target="_blank" onclick="openW('e')">
        <img src="somepic.png" alt="some pic">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So you manually resize the window using your platform *after* the window opens? The browser does not remember things like that. You can specify a size in the `window.open()` call however.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the window size in the window.open call. Something like this:

```
window.open(myFancyURL, "_blank", 'width=100, height=100')
```

Will open a new window of 100px wide by 100px tall. See the Mozilla docs for window.open for more features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

With the code below, you can manage your size window:

```
<script>
    function openW(a) {
        var i = new Image();
        i.src = "somepic.png";

        // open up a new blank
        var w = window.open("", "test", "resizable,height=260,width=370");

        w.document.write('<img src="' + i.src + '">');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for something like this

NOTE: Will not pop in a stacksnippet

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "IMG") {
      const img = e.target;
      const w = img.width;
      const h = img.height;
      // open up a new blank
      let win = window.open("", "img", "scrollbars,width=" + (w + 10) + ",height=" + (h + 10));
      if (win) {
        e.preventDefault(); // allow the target
        win.document.write('<img src="' + img.src + '">');
        win.document.close(); // important
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="some pic" />
  </a>
</div>
```